# XML sitemap which includes tt_news articles

Tags: typo3, sitemap, tt-news, xml-sitemap

Currently I'm using [mc_googlesitemap](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/mc_googlesitemap/0.4.2/view/). I've read that I can include tt_news articles in the xml output when using "Google Sitemap for Contents". In the [documentation](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/mc_googlesitemap/0.4.2/view/1/2/#id1246839) you have an option `Table where the contents live` but this is not available for me. I only can choose "Google Sitemap for Contents" and than I have "Selected Pages". There are no such option as seen in the docu and as described [here](http://jweiland.net/typo3/suchmaschinen-optimierung/google-sitemaps.html).

I'm using Typo3 4.7.10 and mc_googlesitemap 0.4.2.

I also tried weeaar_googlesitemap but here in the xml output I only see the page itself where the plugin was configured to display its output. Accessing Web -> GoogleSitemap doesn't work because of the deprecated function

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method t3lib_div::fixed_lgd_pre() in
>   /usr/home/xxx/typo3conf/ext/weeaar_googlesitemap/mod1/index.php
>   on line 121

I found [this fix](http://www.brainworxx.de/brainlife/2012/01/05/typo3-t3lib_divfixed_lgd_pre-fixen-der-core-funktion/) but currently I cannot adapt the source files because I've no permissions.

How do I get an xml sitemap which can also display me tt_news articles of a certain category?

**Edit:**

I fixed the deprecated warning and my TS looks like the following (for the weaar sitemap):

```
#############################
# Sitemap
#############################
sitemap = PAGE
sitemap {
  typeNum = 200
  10 >
  10 < plugin.tx_weeaargooglesitemap_pi1
  10.pid_list = 1
  10.recursive = 0
  10.allowedDoktypes = 2,1,4
  10.domain = http://www.domain.com/
  10.tt_news.single_page {
    1 = 78
    1.pid_list = 77
  }
  10.tt_news {
    disabledParameter = day,month,year
  }

  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/xml
    no_cache = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
  }
}
```

I have the following problems:

- Hidden Pages are shown in my sitemap.xml (there is no page with doktype 5 allowed)
- tt_news articles are not displayed (what is wrong with my configuration?)

Explanation:

```
10.pid_list = 1 // this is my main entry point  
10.tt_news.single_page.1 = 78 // this is my page id where the single view of tt_news resides  
10.tt_news.single_page.1.pid_list = 77 // this is my sysfolder where the news are placed
```

What I'm doing wrong? Alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [tq_seo](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tq_seo) which does all the SEO magic for your TYPO3 site. It's quite easy but also powerful.